# How to invoke a signal from a custom widget at runtime

Tags: qt, custom-controls

1. We have a custom widget plugin, lets say myprogressbar.
2. We have an exe. The exe has a dialog.ui file which has the custom plugin.
3. We use quiloader to load the file at runtime, which loads the custom plugin. I have verified that, the constructor of myprogressbar is invoked when we load dialog.ui file.

Now my question is how to declare signals and slot so that at runtime the **exe would emit**   a signal and corresponding slot would in the custom plugin would be invoked.

I found some clue [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq16-dynamicqobject.html) , how do I do it.

Regards,